# How can i separate these strings in iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray, separator

Below is a sample data received using Json serialization

```
(
1c581b4a4ec43727,
39e0ec2adcf8bae4,
3a66203c191d9016,
3de3d080a7f1ae38
)
```

I tried using:

```
 NSArray *myVoucherCodes = [[NSArray alloc]init];
 myVoucherCodes = [[[json valueForKey:@"VoucherCodes"] objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
 vouchercode = myVoucherCodes[0];
```

but it crashes. My error:

```
-[__NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d845b0
```

Is it because it is in another line ? If so, how can I represent the "next line" in code?

Comment: It appears that the data has already been run through NSJSONSerialization to produce an NSArray.  So why not just iterate through the array??

Comment: (See the `()` characters?  That means it's an NSArray.  `{}` would mean it's an NSDictionary.)

Comment: I've originally used [[json valueForKey:@"VoucherCodes"] objectAtIndex:0] and it returns the whole data set shown above.

Comment: omg. I just saw my mistake. Thanks for the help!

Comment: And `[__NSCFArray componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector...` is telling you that what you think is a string is really an NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this

```
NSArray *myVoucherCodes = [[NSArray alloc]init];
 myVoucherCodes = [[[json valueForKey:@"VoucherCodes"] objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
 vouchercode = myVoucherCodes[0];
```

do this

```
NSArray *voucherArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
voucherArray = [json valueForKey:@"VoucherCodes"];

NSString *voucherString = [voucherArray objectAtIndex:0]

NSArray *myVoucherCodes = [[NSArray alloc]init];
myVoucherCodes = [voucherString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

vouchercode = myVoucherCodes[0];
```

The above code will not solve your problem. It'll let you know where the problem is.

Comment: since the data is already an array. all I had to do was do
[[[json valueForKey:@"VoucherCodes"] objectAtIndex:0][0]

Comment: Thats correct. But if you try not to nest everything in one line, it'll be easier to find where you are going wrong, instead of getting lost when Xcode tells you "componentsSeparatedByString error". (I personally use this as a good practice, even if it leads to more lines of code)

Answer (score 0):

since the data is already an array. all I had to do was:

```
[[[json valueForKey:@"VoucherCodes"] objectAtIndex:0][0]
```